# NoMethodError: undefined method 'password' while creating a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

This is my User_Controller, normal scaffold

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the User model(User.rb) that im working on:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :fname, :lname, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                   :confirmation => true,
                   :length => {:within => 6..30}
end
```

While I created this model, I forgot that user should have a "password" attribute. So I made a migration for password. But ever since then I keep getting this error whenever I create a user:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `password' for #<User:0x00000100b11560>
```

sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: Did you add the password to the model?

Comment: Dave, this is exactly what im questioning myself too. I did the migration and it has a column named "Password" and made it accessible…what else do i need to do in order to "add the password to the (user) model"?

Comment: "Password" *with* an upper-case? Please add the relevant model code to the question.

Comment: Dave, it is the "P"!! i got it fix!! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the password column in users table, login to mysql and do `DESC users`

Either you might have missed to run migration or your migration should have some problem

Comment: I do, here is what the notation gem gives me in User.rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  username   :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  fname      :string(255)
#  lname      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  Password   :string(255)
#

Comment: Looks like you have created the migration for password with P capital, fixing this should fix the problem

Comment: It seems Password is uppercase.
Try redoing your migration with lowercase password and trying again.

Comment: I will try…but it worked before since I successfully created one user in my database…

Answer (score 2):

Mark them as attributes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

---

**UPDATE** 11-2015

With current rails this method has changed to `attr_accessor`. You shouldn't have to declare the confirmation as an attribute, just the `confirmation: true` should suffice.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 6..20 }, confirmation: true
end
```